# Is it always true that $\prod_{j=1}^{w}{(2s_j + 1)} \equiv 1 \pmod 4$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, examples-counterexamples, products, parity

My question is pretty basic.

Here it goes:

> Is it always true that $$\prod_{j=1}^{w}{(2s_j + 1)} \equiv 1 \pmod  4$$
>   where the $s_j$'s are positive integers, and may be odd or even?

We can perhaps assume that $w \geq 10$.

I am thinking that it might be possible to disprove this, but I cannot think of a counterexample at this moment.

**MY ATTEMPT**

How about 
$$w=10$$
$$s_1 = s_2 = s_3 = s_4 = s_5 = s_6 = s_7 = s_8 = s_9 = 2$$
and
$$s_{10} = 1$$
for a counterexample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each factor on the left hand side may be either $\equiv 1$ or $\equiv 3\bmod 4$. If there are an odd number of the latter (i.e. an odd number of odd $s_j$), the product will be $\equiv 3\bmod 4$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @CarlSchildkraut!  Before I accept your answer, can you please confirm if you meant to say "... (i.e. an odd number of *odd* $s_j$'s) ..."?

Comment: @JoseArnaldoBebitaDris Yes - thanks for pointing that out. I've corrected the typo now.

Answer (score 1):

Since $2x+1\equiv(-1)^x\pmod 4$, we have
$$\prod_{j=1}^{w}{(2s_j + 1)} \equiv (-1)^{\sum_{j}s_j} \pmod  4$$
hence
$$\prod_{j=1}^{w}{(2s_j + 1)} \equiv 1\pmod 4\iff\sum_{j=1}^ws_j\equiv 0\pmod 2$$